# "unfold" for common lisp?

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp, reduce, fold

I learned quite a bit of scheme from SICP but am more interested in common lisp now. I know common lisp's `fold` is `reduce`, with special arguments for left or right folding, but what is the equivalent of `unfold`? Googling has not helped much. In fact I get the impression there is no unfold???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Common Lisp has `(loop ... collect ...)`.  Compare

```
(loop for x from 1 to 10 collect (* x x))
```

with its equivalence using `unfold`:

```
(unfold (lambda (x) (> x 10))
  (lambda (x) (* x x))
  (lambda (x) (+ x 1))
  1)
```

In general, `(unfold p f g seed)` is basically

```
(loop for x = seed then (g x) until (p x) collect (f x))
```

Edit: fix typo

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I've been playing around with loop for the past hour :P its great stuff! I love when programming languages have these little sort of embedded sublanguages which have their own syntax and set of rules to understand, like format strings. Loop is powerful stuff!

Answer (score 3):

The common lisp hyperspec doesn't define an `unfold` function, but you can certainly write your own.  Its scheme definition translates almost symbol for symbol.

Comment: Thanks. That's unfortunate, but I suppose yes I'll write my own. I really like scheme for being so pure and having such beautiful functional goodness, but I've sort of resigned myself to learning the tangled, yet expressive common lisp. It's sort of like learning english rather than esperanto, you know?